# how do I do a sum over partition in spark sql?

Tags: sql, apache-spark

spark sql is just different enough from the engines I use that it breaks all my code

this statement

```
case when sum(flag = 'Y') over (partition by id) > 0
     then 'Y' else 'N' end as flag
```

is supposed to return Y if any flag field of a given id is Y and it doesn't work because sum function in spark can only take numeric types. is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not valid SQL -- it happens to work in MySQL but not in most databases.

The Standard SQL approach will work, using a `CASE` expression:

```
(case when sum(case when flag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) > 0
     then 'Y' else 'N'
 end) as flag
```

Or, assuming that `flag` only takes on the values of `'Y'` and `'N'`, you can simplify the logic to:

```
min(flag) over (partition by id) as flag
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the Boolean `flag = 'Y'` to an integer in order to sum it up:

```
case when sum(int(flag = 'Y')) over (partition by id) > 0
     then 'Y' else 'N' end as flag
```